# How to know when ajax file upload has fully completed, before lengthy server-side processing of the file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am uploading a file using JQuery, ajax and FormData, with PHP on the server end. The file upload works, and I have a progress bar that successfully updates during the upload. However, when the files are small or the network connection is fast, the last progress event received might not be at 100% (it might be less than 90%). This is a problem since I want to change the progress bar text after the file transfer to indicate that server-side processing is taking place (converting PDF to images, which may take some time).

Is there any way I can know when the file transfer is complete, so that I can make sure the progress bar is not stuck at an anonymous/impatience-inducing/oh-no-it-stopped-working-better-refresh-and-try-again 89% for the entire duration of the server-side processing?

My upload code in case it's relevant (I've removed `beforeSend`, `success` and `complete` for brevity):

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form-file-upload')[0]);
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/file-upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : "json",
  xhr: function() {
    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if(myXhr.upload){
      myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
          var percent = (100*e.loaded/e.total).toFixed(0);
          $('#form-file-upload-progress-percent').html(percent + ' %');
          $('#form-file-upload-progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css({width: percent + '%'});
        }
      }, false);
    }
    return myXhr;
  },
  beforeSend: // code executed before submission
  success: // code executed after successful server-side processing
  complete: // code executed after server-side processing
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
});
```

Comment: sort of like asking ..`can i trust progress event?`. Only other way I can think of would be polling server with another request

Answer (score 0):

`upload` has the same events as the primary xhr. So `myXhr.upload.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete);` is what you're looking for.